# Running two ajax requests in sequence (call only after success)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a simple question regarding multiple ajax calls, performing each call in sequence. I have a button that posts the current page's form (which will write the form values into session), then I want to call another page (GET) after these session variables are set.

The problem is, I run both calls in a function and if the first post does not make it through in time, the session values are not present on the other script which are required.

Here's my button's function:

```
function generateFP() {
    $.post("test.php", $("#webcto_form").serialize());
    loadPage('getpage.php?page=fpreq','page_contents');
}
```

And my loadPage function:

```
function loadPage(filename,id){
    $("#page_contents").load(filename);
}
```

Is it possible to use the shorthand ajax ($.post/.load) in conjunction with a success? I want to change my generateFP to call the loadPage function after successfully submitting the form.

I've seen standard $.ajax documentation explaining how to build a success function but have not yet found any information using the syntax that I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you. You will be calling the loadPage function in a success event handler function.

```
function generateFP() {
    $.post("test.php", $("#webcto_form").serialize(), function(data){
       //this is the success callback function
       //data parameter holds the response returned from the post if you need it.
       loadPage('getpage.php?page=fpreq','page_contents');
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The jQuery Post method allows a success handler (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
function generateFP() {
    $.post("test.php", $("#webcto_form").serialize(), function(){
        loadPage('getpage.php?page=fpreq','page_contents');
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you could modify your test.php script to return you the information you are after from your second request:

```
function generateFP() {
    $.post("test.php", $("#webcto_form").serialize(), function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Where `data` is the output of your test.php script.

Comment: Thank you for the last bit -- I was also curious how to get a response back from that post call.

Comment: Please be aware not to use console.log() directly in your production code if you want your code to run on all browsers. Older versions of IE do not support console object.